# Spanning categories in Highcharts across multiple points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to make my categories span across multiple data points in Highcharts.  Here is an example fidde: http://jsfiddle.net/pn9qvz7v/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        }]
    });
});
```

In my example, I'd like for the "Jan" category to span across the 1 and 2 data points, the "Feb" category to span across the 3 and 4 data points, and the "Mar" category to span across the 5 and 6 data points.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the x values of your data to achieve this.

Instead of:

```
data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Supply x/y pairs. The x value is the category index, and in this case, you need to provide one x value below the category index, and one above:

```
data: [
  [-0.25,1], 
  [0.25,2], 
  [0.75,3], 
  [1.25,4], 
  [1.75,5], 
  [2.25,6]
]
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/pn9qvz7v/1/

Though, if you are using dates, why not just use a `datetime` x axis type, and provide the actual dates?

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type

Comment: If I were to use a datetime x-axis, is it possible to still compartmentalize the x-axis labeling to months?  I have daily data and ideally instead of having a label for each day of the month, I'd just like to have the months labels so that the chart doesn't look terrible if the data is spread out over many months.

Comment: Yes, if you set a tickInterval of 30 days (2592000000), the chart will place a label for each month.